# zsh: command not found: mkdir

Tags: terminal, zsh, tex-live

I'm missing a path for **Tex Live** to put my .bib file into.
That's why I'm trying to create some folders via terminal.
I found the commands [here](https://adamliter.org/content/LaTeX/latex-workshop-for-linguists.pdf)(page 4).
Weirdly I get an error, I have no clue what zsh is telling me here. I'm a scripting noob, pls excuse my ignorance. But from what I can tell this should be a basic command, shouldn't it?

```
@A1418_m2017_5004345941 / %mkdir -p $(kpsewhich
--var-value=TEXMFHOME)/{doc,generic,scripts,source} && \ mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME)/bibtex/{bib,bst} && \ mkdir -p $(kpsewhich
--var-value=TEXMFHOME)/fonts/{afm,map,misc,pk,source,tfm,type1} && \ mkdir -p $(kpsewhich
--var-value=TEXMFHOME)/tex/{context,generic,latex,plain,xelatex,xetex} && \ mkdir -p $(kpsewhich
--var-value=TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/biblatex/{bbx,cbx}

zsh: command not found:  mkdir @A1418_m2017_5004345941 / %
```

Comment: You appear to have copied this without pasting it correctly. All those backslashes are probably supposed to be line-continuation characters, but without the newlines they are meant to escape, they are just escaping the following space, which is then treated as part of the following word. You are trying to run the command `\ mkdir` (with a leading space), not `mkdir`.

Comment: (I edited the question to use a code block rather than a quote block, but may not have preserved the actual formatting of your original code.)

Comment: oh my.
solved.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just inserted this line into `~/.zprofile`

```
# Default PATHs
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```

And the errors disappeared